# Does Entity Framework Database First know about unique keys set in the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

EF6.

I have a project using EF6 Database first.

My database table **had** a unique key on 6 columns. All was working well in the project. I then realized the unique key was incorrect and I didn't need it so I deleted it from the database.

I have a `Product` which contains an `ICollection<ProdPrice> ProdPrices`.

Now, when I use `Product product = db.Products.Find(id);` I get a product but the ProdPrices collection only contains 6 items when it should contain 12. (The first 6 items are in the list).

If I delete the first item from the db and run the code again, 6 items are returned - items 2 - 7.

If I change one of the values in a column that **was** in the unique key that item will come though in the code.

So I'm thinking EF is somehow remembering the unique key and only returning the first items that do not conflict with the unique key.

I tried to "update model from database" in the edml file - didn't resolve the issue. So I deleted the ProdPrice table from the edml and the "update model from database" - didn't work.

So my question is - Am I correct is saying EF is remembering the deleted unique key? If yes, how do I get it to forget about it? If I am incorrect, then can you explain what is actually happening?

EDIT: SQL generated by the call to the database - standard select statement which returns all 12 records when run in SSMS (columns removed for ease of reading) :

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ProdPriceID] AS [ProdPriceID], 
[Extent1].[ProdID] AS [ProdID],
[Extent1].[PermanentlyDelete] AS [PermanentlyDelete], 
[Extent1].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated]
FROM [dbo].[ProdPrice] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[ProdID] = 67577
```

Here are the results so you can see I get 12 records.

[image: SSMS Results]

Code Result:

[image: Code Result]

So I decided to just request the prices for the product - I get 12 results, this is really confusing me:

[image: Prices only]

EDIT:
I thought I had resolved it...
To resolve (and test further) I decided to recreate the ProdPrice table in the db - I did this by generating the script using MSSSMS and including the data so I had an exact copy of the table, calling it ProdPrice2.

I had both ProdPrice and ProdPrice2 Entities in my system (This confirmed I'm still connected to the correct database). ProdPrice still only returned records that did not conflict with the original Unique Index. ProdPrice2 - returned all records!

Whoop, thought that was it - I then removed ProdPrice from my system, leaving ProdPrice2 - I ran the system, ProdPrice2 now only has 6 records, not the 12 I had previously!!!

I added ProdPrice back in. ProdPrice2 still has 6 records, ProdPrice now has all expected records.

I'M STUMPED!!!! This is really stopping my development! I can't continue until this is resolved!

Comment: *So I deleted the ProdPrice table from the edml and the "update model from database" - didn't work* What didn't work? Was the `ProdPrice` table not re-entered into the class model. Did it have the same keys as before? If it's the latter, I suspect you simply updated against the wrong database. Check the connection string in the edmx project.

Comment: @GertArnold I suppose I should have said "didn't resolve the issue" rather than "didn't work", I've updated my question. It's isn't a connection string issue. I've added further tables during testing and those changes are reflected in my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After wrestling with this for a couple of days and some excellent help and suggestions from @AlbertoMonteiro I couldn't get the behaviour I expected.

After continuing to try various things, and debugging, I eventually hit some code I forgot I had in there...!

So the answer to the original question

> Does Entity Framework Database First know about unique keys set in the database?

is, no Entity Framework Database First DOESN'T know about unique keys set in the database.

EF does however, use any overridden Equals() functions when creating lists of entities. In my code I had overridden the Equals functions to mimic the unique keys in the database meaning when I added to lists of Prices I could match "duplicates" and merge them together. This code resulted in my Prices list not being fully populated now that I had changed the way I wanted the system to work.

The answer is that I'm an idiot and I should have remembered the code I had written. I will leave this question here as it may stop someone losing a couple of days development in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework in this question, doesn't worry about your deleted Unique Key, also this Unique Key doesn't filter the data when you select something, the unique key prevents that you can not add another row with the same unique key.

So again, this unique key isn't a trouble, and EF doesn't care about it.

But you can debug the SQL generated from EF and check why you are getting only 6 items from property **ProdPrices**.

We can use the **Database.Log** property from context, to analyze the SQL generated.

You said that you have this code line `Product product = db.Products.Find(id);`

Lets modify it a little bit to analyze the sql.

```
//Add breakpoint in this line
Product product = db.Products.Find(id); 
db.Database.Log = sql => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sql);
var prodPrices = product.ProdPrices.ToList();
//Next line
```

- Add a breackpoint in first line(that find the product)
- Press <kbd>F10</kbd>(Step over) 3 times
- Breakpoint must be now in next line of code after the creation of **prodPrices**
- Open the Output window
- The SQL generated from ProdPrice, should be there

Analyze the SQL query, execute in SSMS and check the result.

I tried this in my machine, but it works fine:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyClass())
        {
            if (!ctx.Products.Any())
            {
                var product = new Product
                {
                    ProdPrices = new List<ProdPrice>
                    {
                        new ProdPrice {PermanentlyDelete = true, DateCreated = new DateTime(2015,12,29,18,28,27)},
                        new ProdPrice {PermanentlyDelete = true, DateCreated = new DateTime(2015,12,29,18,28,28)},
                        new ProdPrice {PermanentlyDelete = true, DateCreated = new DateTime(2015,12,29,18,28,28)},
                        new ProdPrice {PermanentlyDelete = true, DateCreated = new DateTime(2015,12,29,18,28,29)},
                        new ProdPrice {PermanentlyDelete = true, DateCreated = new DateTime(2015,12,29,18,28,29)},
                        new ProdPrice {PermanentlyDelete = true, DateCreated = new DateTime(2015,12,30,19,08,38)},
                        new ProdPrice {PermanentlyDelete = false, DateCreated = new DateTime(2015,12,31,10,18,06)},
                        new ProdPrice {PermanentlyDelete = false, DateCreated = new DateTime(2015,12,31,10,18,06)},
                        new ProdPrice {PermanentlyDelete = false, DateCreated = new DateTime(2015,12,31,10,18,07)},
                        new ProdPrice {PermanentlyDelete = false, DateCreated = new DateTime(2015,12,31,10,18,07)},
                        new ProdPrice {PermanentlyDelete = false, DateCreated = new DateTime(2015,12,31,10,18,08)},
                        new ProdPrice {PermanentlyDelete = false, DateCreated = new DateTime(2015,12,31,10,18,08)},
                    }
                };

                ctx.Products.Add(product);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine("Saved");
            }
        }
        using (var ctx = new MyClass())
        {
            var product = ctx.Products.Find(1);
            var count = product.ProdPrices.Count;
            Console.WriteLine(count);
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProdPrice> ProdPrices { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public long ProdID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProdPrice> ProdPrices { get; set; }
}

public class ProdPrice
{
    public long ProdPriceID { get; set; }
    public bool PermanentlyDelete { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Tried this and the SQL is a standard select statement - all 12 rows are returned when I run in SSMS!!! Weird!

Comment: @Rick can you post the SQL generated?

Comment: If you run `product.ProdPrices.ToList().Count` whats the value?

Comment: The value I get is 6

Comment: @Rick This is really weird. Can you try to use `product.ProdPrices.Take(20).ToList().Count` ?

Comment: Still get 6 - I've added some screenshots into the question.

Comment: @Rick I am going to try to reproduce this same data in my computer, and check the results

Comment: @Rick did you tried `db.Products.SelectMany(x => x.ProdPrices)`

Comment: Check my latest update in the question - when I request only the prices for that product, I get 12!! I'm so confused as to what is happening!

Comment: @Rick I saw, and I also tried it in my machine, but it works

Comment: That's usually the case!!! Thanks for your help... No Doubt it's some stupid  issue somewhere - hopefully I'll figure it out soon!!!

Comment: @Rick I added in my answer what I have tried, could you create a console application, and do the same thing, but pointing to same database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99402/discussion-between-alberto-monteiro-and-rick).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are creating the dbcontext only once, and that too is static.

When ever you are making a fetch/write call to db create a new context, that should do.

Again,

Create a base class which contains DbContext and inherit that class every time you need to talk to the db.

Something like this

```
public class TheDBEntities
{
    private TheDBEntities _context = new TheDBEntities();

    protected TheDBEntities Context { get; private set; }

    protected TheDataContext()
    {

        Context = _context;
    }


    protected void SaveChanges()
    {
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected void SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        Context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }


}


public class DBBusinessLayer: TheDBEntities
{
    public DBBusinessLayer() { }

    public void GetData(int id)
    {
        // use it here Context.<yourentities>
    }
}
```

Comment: Why expose `protected void SaveChangesAsync()`? It will just run syncronously and be equivalent to `SaveChanges()`. Mark the method as `protected async Task SaveChangesAsync()` or don't expose it at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - @kai